# In python, how do I write to a specific location in a file?

Tags: python, fwrite

I have an html file. I want to create a python script that writes content to the html file at a specific location. I know I could write to a *specific line* in the html file using .readlines() and .writelines() but that's not what I want to do. I want to write content to a specific html script tag in the html file. How can I create a python program that writes content to the specific html script tag in my html file?
Is it possible?

Comment: Is the data you want to write *exactly* the same length as the data it's replacing? If not, you'll have to rewrite at least every byte from where you perform the insertion to the end of the file.

Comment: Firstly yes it is possible. It would be better if you could show us the HTML you are working with... if it is very large then just paste the part of interest. Also, I suggest you take a look into beautiful soup library in python...

Comment: If you want to edit or add something to html then your best to use an HTML parser, that will give you an html tree you can navigate to elements in and add on new elements etc then write it back out to a file